# Xray for JIRA Jenkins Plugin, TestNG XML Results Import task failure

Tags: jenkins, plugins, jira, x-ray

this is my 1st question, any help will be greatly appreciated.
I need to import test results from Jenkins to Xray.
To do so I:

- set up Xray for JIRA Jenkins Plugin;
- configured Xray Server/DC integration with Jenkins;
- tested connection and it's successful;
- went to my Jenkins project configuration and set up post-build Action 'Xray:Result Import Task';
- under parameters of 'Xray:Result Import Task' I was trying to specify Execution Report File (file path with file name).

AND here is my question: what exact input is supposed to be here?
I tried URL to my test execution issue already created in Xray, testng.xml. myTestExecution.xml file - nope. Doesn't work. I'm missing smthng here((

Can't get what is meant by:
file path with file name.

My Results Import task fails with error below.

```
Starting XRAY: Results Import Task...
##########################################################
####     Xray is importing the execution results      ####
##########################################################
0 files found. Please make sure the path provided is valid and is not a directory
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
com.xpandit.plugins.xrayjenkins.exceptions.XrayJenkinsGenericException: 0 files found. Please make sure the path provided is valid and is not a directory
    at com.xpandit.plugins.xrayjenkins.Utils.FileUtils.getFiles(FileUtils.java:180)
    at com.xpandit.plugins.xrayjenkins.task.XrayImportBuilder.perform(XrayImportBuilder.java:563)
    at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep.perform(SimpleBuildStep.java:112)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:78)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1919)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
Build step 'Xray: Results Import Task' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- set up Xray for JIRA Jenkins Plugin;
- configured Xray Server/DC integration with Jenkins;
- tested connection and it's successful;
- went to my Jenkins project configuration and set up 2 post-build Actions:

1. 'Publish TestNG Results'
   TestNG XML report pattern: **/target/surefire-reports/testng-results.xml
2. 'Xray:Result Import Task':

- Jira Instance: Jira Instance;
- Format: TestNG XML;
- Execution Report File (file path with file name): **/testng-results.xml (generated by 'Publish TestNG Results' action);
- Test Execution Key: JIRA-123 (Jira Test execution issue);